# Migrar tabla desde SQL server hacia MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, asp

Tengo 2 sistemas (Uno en **asp** y otro en **PHP**)
El que está en asp está conectado a SQL server y el PHP a MySQL.

En `SQL Server` tengo una tabla llamada "Clientes". Esta tabla se actualiza cada 2 o 3 días.

En `MySQL`, tengo replicada esa misma tabla clientes que alimenta al sistema en `PHP`.

De momento están trabajando de manera "OFFLINE",es decir, que nunca se encuentra actualizada la tabla "Clientes" del `MySQL`, ya que es un proceso que se realiza manualmente cada 2 semanas.

Mi pregunta es si existe la posibilidad de realizar algún script o algo que permita hacer la actualización automáticamente cada día, o manualmente, pero que sea simple, como presionar un botón para que corra el script y actualice.

---

De la manera que lo estoy haciendo ahora es realizar el exporte desde SQL Server de la tabla "clientes", y luego realizo un import en MySQL.

Pero esta es una tarea manual que no puedo realizar siempre, por lo que necesito alguna alternativa para que alguien con pocos conocimientos lo pueda hacer sin nungún problema.

---

Detallo un poco más cómo realizo el proceso que me lleva mucho tiempo y corro riesgo de cometer errores en el camino. (Hay veces que lo tiene que realizar alguien "NO TÉCNICO")

Actualmente lo que hago es exportar un csv, cargarlo en una tabla auxiliar (`MySQL`) y luego realizar la consulta para insertar desde la tabla auxiliar (`MySQL`) a la tabla principal (`MySQL`)

Hay forma de realizar esto de otra manera?

Probé varias cosas pero no tuve éxito hasta ahora:

Desde acceder con `php` a `SQL Server` hasta linkear y configurar los servidores.

Nada de eso me funcionó.

¿Existe la posibilidad de generar algún script algo similar para automatizar el proceso que describí al comienzo?

Comment: Pepe, a tu pregunta le hacen falta algunos puntos como: código que hayas utilizado para intentar lograr lo que necesitas, especificar correctamente cual es la pregunta. Si tu pregunta es si se puede hacer la respuesta es **si**, pero a su vez es demasiado amplia ya que los métodos pueden ser varios. Intenta ser más específico y a la vez comparte con nosotros como lo has intentado, así se podrá ayudarte.

Comment: Agregué la forma en que lo hago actualmente.

Comment: Depende desde donde quieras automatizar, si el click que quieres realizar, estará en el entorno SQL server, deberias tener una automatización tipo push (donde del lado de mysql, vas a tener que implementar un servicio que reciba la data), en cambio si la acción de inicio, va a estar desde el lado del servidor mysql, lo que seria un pull. seguramente vas a tener que desarrollar una consulta al SQL server desde esta plataforma.

Comment: @PaulRM Sería la segunda opción. Cómo debería ser? Soy un poco nuevo en esto y tengo miedo de liarla :P Tenés algún ejemplo, página o tutorial donde pueda ver más o menos cómo se hace?

Comment: @Pepemujica, lametablemente no conosco un tutorial completo, justamente el problema principal de tu pregunta es que para resolverla tienes que lidiar con varias partes, hay varios caminos, y no necesariamente un camino esta bien y el otro mal. Pero no temas liara, estudia en que entorno estas mas cómodo y decide poner la mayor funcionalidad en ese.
Yo me siento mas cómodo en PHP del lado Linux, seguiria las instrucciones de http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx para tener un acceso a MSSQL y luego grabar en MySQL

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Hice un segundo update, quizás con eso se entienda un poco más lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

En un principio, si la tabla del SQL Server se actualiza cada 2 o 3 días, podrías actualizar el proceso que actualiza esa tabla para que también actualice la tabla del MySQL. No habría problema en usar ODBC para conectar al MySQL desde la misma aplicación que se conecta al SQL Server.

Estoy limitado a responderte por tu comentario sobre "pocos conocimientos", quizás puedas expandirte en tus posibilidades.

La tarea que haces manualmente (exportar SQL Server -> importar en MySQL) podrías automatizarla con algún script, ya sea bash (Linux) o vbs (Windows) y luego usar cronjob (Linux) o Tareas Programadas (Windows) para que corra una vez por día, por hora, por semana o como quieras programarla.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder. Alguien con pocos conocimientos sería un administrativo por ejemplo, que no sabe nada de SQL o programación. Me interesa la parte de automatizar con algún script. Cómo sería?

Comment: Lo que yo hago es desde SQL server exportar la tabla a cvs. Y luego en MySQL hago el import de ese csv.

Comment: Cómo sería el tema del script? Porque busqué por varios lugares pero no pude encontrar mucho

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Hice un segundo update, quizás con eso se entienda un poco más lo que necesito

Comment: Hola, bueno, el tema del administrativo lo podemos descartar, porque asumo que vos no sos el administrativo y automatizando un script evitarías la interacción humana para realizar la tarea.

Comment: Sobre el script, tenés conocimientos de PHP, VBS o algún lenguaje de programación como para indicarte mejor?

Comment: Sí, algo de PHP

Comment: Perdón por la demora, no me llegaron las notificaciones de tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso particular que necesitas la información actualizada en ambos `SMBD`, te recomiendo investigar acerca de servidores vinculados (`linked servers`), para de esta forma poder insertar directamente desde `SQL Server` hacia la tabla en `MySQL`, ya sea mediante un `stored procedure` o un `trigger` directamente en tu tabla clientes.

Una vez tengas configurado tu servidor vinculado, podrás insertar a MySQL de la siguiente manera

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM MySQL_Clientes')
SELECT * FROM dbo.SQLServer_Clientes
```

aquí te dejo algunos vínculos que te pueden ayudar

[Vincular MySQL con SQL Server](http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2016/08/linkear-mysql-con-sql-server.html)

[Configuring a MySQL linked server on SQL Server 2008](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mysql-linked-server-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Lamentablemente no puedo realizar la vinculación entre los servidores. hice un segundo update. Quizás con eso pueda orientarte un poco más con lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Hola!! ya pude hacer la vinculación, pero no me queda claro cómo hacer la consulta desde MySQL. No me funcionó la cosulta que dejaste más arriba

Comment: Me retorna este mensaje: OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.12-log]Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".